# Spring Cloud Stream annotation support question

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

With Spring Cloud Stream annotations being deprecated, is there a targeted release, or better yet, a targeted date for the release after which the annotation-based configuration will no longer be supported? Our team has quite a bit of code implemented using annotations, and we are trying to determine when we should begin the effort to convert this code to the functional model, allowing plenty of lead time to do so. So, if anyone from the Spring community knows the answer to this or can give a best guess as to when that may be, it would be most helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been removed in the upcoming 4.0 release (which is part of Spring Cloud 2022.0.0) currently scheduled at the end of November.

This is a major upgrade (based on Spring Framework 6, Java 17).